# Raise for status on Werkzeug response

Tags: python, werkzeug

Is there an elegant way to raise for status on Werkzeug response? Similar to `raise_for_status()` in `requests.Response`? In particular I don't want to get the `status_code` and compare it with HTTP codes and raise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to *raise* with this, the assertion will do it for you. If the response is not `200`, then it fails the assertion. You can add to `status` if you need to change the expected response, but you should at least set it to `{200}` (e.g. `status = {200} if not status else status`)

```
res = client.get(url)
assert res.status_code in status, f'{res.status_code} blah blah failed {url}, etc...'
```

Is there a reason you can't check for the expected status codes? You can even get the 'failure' ones from `werkzeug.exceptions`